# How do you make a metallic bonded compound stay liquid? Necessary for flying vehicles

Tags: chemistry, flight

I have a fuel that has a lot of metallic bonds but I need it as a liquid to be used in engines. Otherwise I have to figure out how to use a solid fuel in the air non-rocket style. It reacts with water to release a ton of energy and H2, which is used for air travel. I don't need warning about using H2, it is a byproduct and the risks doesn't out weight the rewards. By using the fuel, it make a ton of H2 which fills up the dirigibles and blimps that people use, like ships of the sky. Is there a way to like just grind it up and put it in a liquid while still reacting with water? Am I just overthinking this and should just relax about this?

EDIT1: The elements are Bi, Al, Mg, Pu

EDIT2: As commentors pointed out, you could use Hg or Ga, which I will because that makes sense in the story. Adds something I was wanting to fit in. Quick question, this mixture isn't flammable via incendiary bullets? or is there a way to make incendiary bullets with this mixture?

EDIT3: It matters because if there isn't a way to make it fluid, then I'd have to use a more steam/nuclear/punk over a sleeker look. Its still clunky because set in 1880's, but if fluid fuel, then allows for different paths I can take. I am currently thinking of combining both solid and fluid, just to show that it was a transitional period, but if no fluid, then I wont bother

Comment: Different metals will have different ways of keeping them liquid, so it would help if you told us what metal(s) you're using. If you can't because you're not that far along, then you're definitely asking the question too early. From a storybuilding perspective, you shouldn't bother with many details you don't intend to use. So you might be overthinking the issue. Worldbuilding is about simplification. Yes, you can get into all the detail you want, but it's also easy to chase really deep down a rabbit hole you don't need to be in. So you tell us. Do you need this? If so, details please!

Comment: [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(element)) is a metal, so it has a lot of metallic bonds by definition. It is also a liquid at usual temperatures. In fact, if I think about it, *all* the metals I know of have a range of temperatures where they are liquids. The question is trivial; all you have to do is heat up the material to above its melting point.

Comment: Perhaps you might look at [gallium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium) which melts just above room temp (it's liquid at human body-temp). I suggest it because it's less toxic than mercury, and you can dissolve things in it (calcium, potassium, sodium, aluminium etc.). I seem to remember coming across s YouTube vid about generating hydrogen renewably by using it as a medium to interface water with. Then [edit] and ask what you need to know.

Comment: Second thoughts, maybe I dreamed the video. If you patent this, I want credit and a percentage of the dosh. The interesting thing is, it worked with aluminium, which normally doesn't react with water to produce hydrogen because of an oxide film that forms, but is easily disperses if in a liquid medium.

Comment: @AlexP  I know that all metals have a melting point, but if I need to melt the metal up to 10000F, then using it as a fuel doesn't work. If it takes more energy than it gives, its not a fuel.

Comment: Do you just want a high-energy metal that can be ***practically*** liquefied, or do you want a metal that's liquid at human-friendly temperatures? Because Iron would be a liquid inside some modern jet engines (1500'C flame temp although 1100'C on the blades) ***and*** releases a ***phenomenal*** amount of energy when burned... Thermal lances are just pure oxygen and burning iron and they give off enough energy to melt ***literally everything*** (4000'C). Failing that, Thermite uses burning Aluminium (or Magnesium) and it puts out enough heat and light to weld train tracks and give you sunburn!

Comment: @Samwise Two of the elements are Al and Mg, so they could produce a lot of heat and steam or H2 gas. Also, should I expand the elements just in case someone doesn't know?

Comment: 10,000 °F (5,500 °C) is a wild exaggeration; most metals would *boil* below that temperature. Different metals melt at different temperatures, some lower, some higher. For example, type metal (an alloy of lead, tin, and antimony, used in olde skoole hot metal printing) melts at about 250 °C (480 °F). Soldering alloy (tin and lead) melts at 183 °C (361 °F). Sodium melts at 98 °C (208 °F), which is lower than the boiling point of water! Gallium melts at 30 °C (​86 °F), which is lower than the body temperature of a human!

Comment: @AlexP Fair enough, I had meant to do 1000, but didn't double count. My bad. I'm currently going with BiAlMgFr, combined with Hg or Ga, sort of like our leaded vs unleaded. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ...why on Earth would you include *plutonium*?!? It doesn't have an especially low melting point, it is primarily notable for nuclear properties that are irrelevant to this application, and it'd be an extremely hazardous and **extremely** expensive material, being an element that has to be synthesized in nuclear reactors. You seem to be starting with a random listing of elements, including some exceedingly improbable ones, and trying to make them a liquid. I would suggest instead looking at actual low-melting alloys...some, like NaK, are basically just what you describe.

Comment: Dies it need to be a liquid at all? You can use powdered, fluidised coal in internal combustion engines. This was used in WWII. It was not a success then but it could work today.

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing! That is awesome! I'll do that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not too attached to bismuth, aluminium, magnesium, and plutonium, might I suggest NaK?

The [sodium-potassium eutectic alloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium%E2%80%93potassium_alloy) is liquid at room temperature and down to -12.6 °C. And like the alkali metals that comprise it, it reacts explosively with water, forming sodium potassium hydroxide, hydrogen gas, and a lot of heat. It can easily produce enough heat to ignite the hydrogen, if there's also oxygen around.

If you're using it as a liquid fuel, you'll need to be very careful about keeping oxygen away from it while it's in storage. The reaction with air isn't as explosive as the reaction with water, but it does form solid oxides that may clog up your plumbing.

(You will also just need to be very careful in general when handling NaK. This stuff is dangerous.)

Comment: I am pretty attached to those elements, the compound, water and an acid leads to lots of H2, so using the fuel fills the blimps and dirigibles that are common place as a form of safe travel. ground travel is usually for poor and heavy cargo.

Comment: The link you provided lead me to an alternative that I'm happy with, Fr. Replace Pu with Fr and Handwavium the rest. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The most stable isotope of francium has a half life of 22 minutes. How is it any sort of candidate for something intended to produce hydrogen by reacting with water?

Comment: Being radioactive and theoretically liquid at room temp. The Handwavium fills in the rest, but I'm reconsidering it, because instead of getting BiO3, I'm getting BiH, which I don't want.

Comment: If you start with a metric ton of francium, after 24 hours you have about 20 femtograms left, and about a metric ton of radium instead. This is why it's the second rarest natural element, which will keep you from ever having it in quantities sufficient to put in any kind of fuel. Radioactivity isn't a benefit here, it makes absolutely no sense to put radioactive materials into a highly reactive chemical fuel used for generating hydrogen.